# jQuery highlight effect not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Here is my ascx page with embedded javascript.

I'd like to highlight the view which I have wrapped in a div tag (div2 for test purposes) when the view changes.

As of now the views change fine, but I cannot get the highlight to work.

Is something wrong with my javascript or am I missing something else??

Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>



<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server">

<asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
   <p>This is View 1</p>
   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Next" onclick="Button1_Click" />
 </asp:View>


 <asp:View ID="View2" runat="server">
    <div id="div2" style="height:auto; width:auto;">
    <p>This is View 2</p>
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Previous" 
        onclick="Button2_Click" />  
    <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Next" onclick="Button3_Click" /> 
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Button1").click(function () {
    $("#div2").effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
    });
    });
    </script>

 </asp:View>


 <asp:View ID="View3" runat="server">
    <p>This is View 3</p>
    <asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" Text="Previous" 
        onclick="Button4_Click1" />

 </asp:View>

 </asp:MultiView>

  </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code Behind:

```
namespace Multiview1.Multiview1
{
public partial class Multiview1UserControl : UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MultiView1.SetActiveView(View1);
    }

   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MultiView1.SetActiveView(View2);
        UpdatePanel1.Update();
    }

    protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MultiView1.SetActiveView(View3);
        UpdatePanel1.Update();
    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MultiView1.SetActiveView(View1);
        UpdatePanel1.Update();
    }

    protected void Button4_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MultiView1.SetActiveView(View2);
        UpdatePanel1.Update();
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Why are you loading multiple versions of jQuery?

Comment: Those questions/problems are easier to solve, when working on the actual HTML, not on some Template, which is yet to be parsed to retrieve HTML.

Comment: @bstakes I just never bothered to take it out. I dont think that should be a problem? I have the jquery slide effect setup in a similar way on a div and it seems to work fine

Comment: Your Button1 has an onclick handler which is set inline. Is it possible that function is not defined, or returning false which is preventing the click handler you are attaching with jQuery from running?

Comment: @bstakes I have a event defined for that in my code behind. The way I understand it, it is possible to fire two or more events on a button click: onclick and onclientclick. Correct me if I am wrong though. Anyways like I said I get no errors and I am able to switch between views without any issues.

Comment: Show your rendered code. Without the code behind, it will be hard to get an answer.

Comment: @mmcglynn Alright:) I have edited my Question to include the code behind as well.

Comment: Can we see the rendered html page source. Or at least the relevant parts of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem appears to be loading multiple versions of jquery.

I've set up a fiddle to show the issue.  When the 2nd jquery library is commented out it works fine when it's not it doesn't work at all.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aTX4F/)

Answer (score 1):

use your Button click like this

```
$("#<%=Button1.ClientID%>").click(function () {
    $("#div2").effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
   });
});
```

As it is an asp.net control.

EDIT :  You are going in wrong direction there is nothing wrong with the jquery click, Problem here is your div tags are inside updatepanel check this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098228/jquery-effect-highlight-not-working-in-asp-net-update-panel)

Comment: Darn I missed that one! Thanks!! But it still doesn't work though.

Comment: @user1266515 : You even have problems with your multiple versions of Jquery.

Comment: Oh I got rid of that I did. Let me fix the question as well.